# Scope of variable in php

Tags: php, class

i have following simple class with `static method` in php which check if record exist then return the record otherwise return `false`

```
  class db{

      public static function isRecord($q,$parameters){  
        $a=self::getinstance()->prepare($q);
        $a->execute($parameters);
        $r=$a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if($r[0]) return $r[0]; 
        if(!$r[0] || $r[0]==0 ) return false;
     }
  }
```

usage

```
  $e=db::isRecord("SELECT itemdesc FROM temptable WHERE invuser=? ",array($invuser));
```

returns `$e` as expected.

but if i use with in simple function like this

```
function canEnterincart(){
    return db::isRecord("SELECT itemdesc FROM temptable WHERE invuser=? ",array($invuser));
}
```

`var_dump(canEnterincart())` always return `false` even if the record exist.

Is this something wrong with the code?

Comment: Where do you think `$invuser` is coming from inside that function?

Comment: Good one I was about to ask the same the array($invuser) inside the function canEnterincart() will be empty if this is the same code being  used and hence query will fail.

Comment: @deceze it is defined out of the function, Ohh seems like you pointed out one issue

Comment: stackoverflow is always helpful even in case of such stupidities. thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the variable as a parameter of the method, like this:

```
function canEnterincart($invuser){
    return db::isRecord("SELECT itemdesc FROM temptable WHERE invuser=? ",array($invuser));
}
```